# How to get a view from a linearlayout in android?

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout

I Want to get different view from a Linearlayout but it always get me one of them . 
Here is mycode :

```
int count = LinearLayoutItemHolder.getChildCount() ;
for(int i = 0 ; i <count ; i++){
   Customview cs = LinearItemHolder.getChildAt(i) ;
   Log.d(TAG,"value of cs " + cs) ;
   Log.d(TAG,"value : " +    cs.txtText.getText() ) ;
}
```

My LinearLayoutHolder has 3 childs but it always return me just last of them.

the value of cs id :

```
run: com.example.mine.happyp.View.CustomView{2a6e0e3 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
                          run: com.example.mine.happyp.View.CustomView{c251ae0 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
                          run: com.example.mine.happyp.View.CustomView{33ce199 V.E...... ......I. 0,0-0,0}
                          run: 3
                          run: com.example.mine.happyp.View.CustomView{2fedc5e V.E...... ........ 0,0-720,660}
                          run: com.example.mine.happyp.View.CustomView{c5ca83f V.E...... ........ 0,660-720,1320}
                          run: com.example.mine.happyp.View.CustomView{e71050c V.E...... ........ 0,1320-720,1980}
```

Comment: so as you can see they are all different, for example: `{e71050c V.E...... ........ 0,1320-720,1980}` - here `e71050c` is a hashCode and `0,1320-720,1980` are the bounds within the parent

Comment: So Why i get the same value ?! @pskink

Comment: because your code set the same value to all your three `CustomView`s

Comment: when i show them in the list , they have different values , I'm using socket to get list of items , is that because of socket.io ? @pskink